# Cannot set some values of an usercontrol from the VS properties Window

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

In a Winforms usercontrol I've integrated a ProgressBar into a Listview, this is one of the properties:

```
''' <summary>
''' The ListView ProgressBar BorderColor
''' </summary>
Public Property ProgressBar_BorderColor As Pen
    Get
        Return _progressBar_bordercolor
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Pen)
        _progressBar_bordercolor = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Well, the problem is that in the properties window I can't change the pens and brush values.

I can change the values manually writting the code, but not in the properties window.

I did something wrong when coding the properties or just these kind of values cannot be changed in the properties window of any other control and not only my control? and why?

What I need to modify to be able to change these values in the properties window of my user control?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that **this is possible** but you have to implement your own **type converter** or custom **editor** to use for your own control.

Comment: @King King thankyou for comment, can you help me to found online reference/tutorial about how to do that? is totally new for me. I think that an InDesign-Time editor should be really much more harder than the type converter, but anyways I think that I've never seen the type converter that you mean so.. I don't know how much hard would be to do that type converter.

Comment: @King King you mean to set the property type as Color and then convert that color to a pen/brush? if yes then I think that I can do it, seems easy, but anyways I would like to know if there is a more "native" way to be able to change those values in the properties window.

Comment: UIDesigners can be a pain to write.  Based in the Property *NAMES*, you really just want to specify colors for various ProgressBar elements rather than actual GDI items (pens, brushes etc).  Internally, you could have private functions to getPen getBrush of the specified color - much easier than a UIDesigner.

Comment: Thanks, then with that info question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to create your GDI objects when used so you can properly dispose of them:

```
Using g as Graphics = Graphics.FromWhereEver, 
           P as New Pen(ProgressBar_BorderColor), 
           Br as New SolidBrush(ProgressBar_BackColor)

    ... draw and paint
    ... paint and draw
End Using          ' Graphics, Pen and Brush properly disposed of
```

It wont make a great deal of difference because I doubt you would sit and change colors back and forth as a hobby, but they aren't being disposed of when a new color value is set.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

· Brush to Color <> Color to Brush

```
Private _progressBar_backcolor As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Red)

Public Property ProgressBar_BackColor As Color
    Get
        Return _progressBar_backcolor.Color
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        _progressBar_backcolor = New SolidBrush(value)
    End Set
End Property
```

· Pen to Color <> Color to Pen

```
Private _progressBar_bordercolor As Pen = New Pen(Color.LightGray)

Public Property ProgressBar_BorderColor As Color
    Get
        Return _progressBar_bordercolor.Color
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        _progressBar_bordercolor = New Pen(value)
    End Set
End Property
```

[image]

Comment: I was curious what the speed difference was in caching GDI objects and thought you might be interested.  In a loop writing to 120 bitmaps using a Pen and a Brush the total difference was 100ms between using a premade Pen and Brush vs creating New ones for each iteration.  Not enough to worry about considering `Using` will dispose of them for us.